# Javascript Fetch Authorization Header

Tags: javascript, react-native, oauth-2.0, oauth, fetch-api

I know, there are a lot of those questions out here but none of them seem to help me with my question so im sorry if im just not able to understand the other questions, so here i come:

I want to use oauth wit discogs.com Prodiver in my react-native app. Since no oauth library fit for Discogs i need to implement this on my own. Discogs documentation tells me which headers i need for my oauth flow (currently at 'request token' step):

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Authorization:
        OAuth oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key",
        oauth_nonce="random_string_or_timestamp",
        oauth_signature="your_consumer_secret&",
        oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
        oauth_timestamp="current_timestamp",
        oauth_callback="your_callback" 
User-Agent: some_user_agent
```

How can i make a get request with javascript and fetch and include those headers? My code right now seems fine to a beginner like me, but it wont get approved by discogs oauth endpoint:

```
const header = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.discogs.v2.plaintext+json',
    Authorization: {
      'OAuth oauth_consumer_key': config.consumerKey, //imported from json
      'oauth_nonce': nonce, //variable
      'oauth_signature': config.consumerSecret, // imported from json
      'oauth_signature_method': "PLAINTEXT",
      'oauth_timestamp': timestamp, // variable
      'oauth_callback': callback // variable
    },
    'User-Agent': config.appUserAgent
 })

 console.log(header)

const response = await fetch(https://api.discogs.com/oauth/request_token, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: header
});

console.log(response)
```

The console log of headers and response logs this:

```
{
  "map": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "accept": "application/vnd.discogs.v2.plaintext+json",
    "authorization": "[object Object]",
    "user-agent": "Jukebox/1.0"
  }
}

{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "F020B207-2E76-46C8-AD23-783A582B873D", "name": "request_token.json", "offset": 0, "size": 90, "type": "application/json"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "F020B207-2E76-46C8-AD23-783A582B873D", "name": "request_token.json", "offset": 0, "size": 90, "type": "application/json"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"access-control-allow-headers": "Content-Type, authorization, User-Agent, Private-Auth-Secret, Discogs-UID", "access-control-allow-methods": "HEAD,OPTIONS,OPTIONS", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "access-control-expose-headers": "Location", "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-29=\":443\"; ma=86400", "cf-cache-status": "DYNAMIC", "cf-ray": "79c05b750af01608-DUS", "content-language": "de", "content-length": "90", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Sun, 19 Feb 2023 16:25:13 GMT", "server": "cloudflare", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15552000", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-discogs-media-type": "discogs.v2", "x-discogs-ratelimit": "60", "x-discogs-ratelimit-remaining": "60", "x-discogs-ratelimit-used": "0", "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN", "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"}}, "ok": false, "status": 500, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "https://api.discogs.com/oauth/request_token"}
```